# How to get MasterVC of a UISplitViewController to show when app is launched as

Tags: ios, swift3, uisplitviewcontroller

trying to get the MasterVC to show up when app is launched. Right now the DetailVC shows when app is launched. Here is my code for `splitViewController`. I'm certain the solution is in the Delegate method.

I'm using CoreData and the model is `var items = [Notes]()`

The ideal outcome is that when the app is launched, the MasterVC `tableView` is showing and by tapping on a `tableCell` the `navigationController` pushes to the DetailVC to display the `indexPath` data. The app already does this. Only need to have MasterVC load upon launch. Thank you.

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    let splitViewController = self.window!.rootViewController as! UISplitViewController
    let navigationController = splitViewController.viewControllers[splitViewController.viewControllers.count-1] as! UINavigationController
    navigationController.topViewController!.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = splitViewController.displayModeButtonItem
    splitViewController.delegate = self as? UISplitViewControllerDelegate
    return true
}
```

UISplitViewController Delegate

```
func splitViewController(_ splitViewController: UISplitViewController, collapseSecondary secondaryViewController: UIViewController, onto primaryViewController: UIViewController) -> Bool {

    guard let secondaryAsNavController = secondaryViewController as? UINavigationController else { return true }
    let topAsDetailController = secondaryAsNavController.topViewController as? MasterViewController
    if topAsDetailController?.items == nil {

        return true
    }
    return false
}
```

Comment: Ok, I discovered the solution.

Comment: I had the following code in the `didFinishLaunchWithOptions`... `splitViewController.delegate = self as? UISplitViewControllerDelegate`.  To fix problem, I removed the following code `as? UISplitViewControllerDelegate` from `didFinishLaunchWithOptions` and added the `UISplitViewControllerDelegate` to the `AppDelegate` `class`. And the app launched with the MasterVC as the `primaryViewController`. Hope this helps someone with this same problem :)

Comment: Please do not answer your question in a comment, but as a proper answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement the `splitViewController(_:collapseSecondary:onto:)` method of the `UISplitViewControllerDelegate` protocol and return `true`:

> **Return Value**
>
> false to let the split view controller try and incorporate the
>   secondary view controller’s content into the collapsed interface or
>   true to indicate that you do not want the split view controller to do
>   anything with the secondary view controller.

The sample code that comes in a new Master-Detail App project:

```
func splitViewController(_ splitViewController: UISplitViewController, collapseSecondary secondaryViewController:UIViewController, onto primaryViewController:UIViewController) -> Bool {
    guard let secondaryAsNavController = secondaryViewController as? UINavigationController else { return false }
    guard let topAsDetailController = secondaryAsNavController.topViewController as? DetailViewController else { return false }
    if topAsDetailController.detailItem == nil {
        // Return true to indicate that we have handled the collapse by doing nothing; the secondary controller will be discarded.
        return true
    }
    return false
}
```